# Does VersionCode matter for an Android AAR library?

Tags: android

Specifically for `aar` generated libraries, does the `versionCode` set either in the manifest or build file matter? Is it used anywhere for anything?

For an `apk` the docs say `versionCode` is used by the Play store API. I couldn't find any reference to `versionCode` relating to `aar`s though.

Answer (score 1):

For aar consumer it doesn't matter - they only need the maven artifact version.

For aar producer it matters - you may want to use it to add specific upgrade code to run only once (from version X to version Y).

I think AGP no longer requires specifying version name or code to non-app modules.